# Fix div position irrespective to the scroll bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, iframe, scroll

I have placed a div present inside a iframe.Inside that div a link is present which is showing a popup.

My Page height is too large(height=1500px). page contains 2 div

1st div contains some logo and some text

2nd one contains only iframe.

when i click the anchor(link) present inside that iframe its showing a popup. i have fixed the position of the popup at he bottom of iframe.

when i scroll up then that popup message is hiding. how to fix the position of the popup so that on scroll on page that will appear on the page.

Means that popup will appear if we scroll down or up.

For this i searched in Google and found that if we write "position: fixed" then it will work. but in case of iframe it is not working.

how to solve this one

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be position:fixed when nested within the parent div and not the iFrame. The iframe has it's own context, so the 'popup' is being fixed in relation to that and not the whole page.

If you put up a fiddle or similar of the code then someone could demonstrate or understand better the problem.

Comment: don't know to write iframe in fiddle. i think we need to call another page inside iframe. it would be helpful to me if you can create a fiddle with iframe which is calling another page.